# How to get the attribute's anim curve that is stemming from animation layer

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I need some help with Animation-related + OpenMaya API.

I am using OpenMaya to iterate rig controllers I have in my scene, targeting mainly at the rotational attributes.
Things work fine if these rotational attributes are keyed (manually). But then things starts to break, if one of the animated iterated attributes stems from animation layer.

As such, is there a way in which I can 'tell' Maya API to have that controller recognize as a curve?

Initially it is erroring out at the `crv.isStatic`, giving error such as `# Error: (kFailure): Object does not exist`
And so, I tried out using `try...except...` which seemingly has bypassed the above error but then it errors out for the latter code on the `math` portion.

```
rig_controls = cmds.ls(selection=True)
m_sel = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
for ctrl in rig_controls:
    m_sel.add(ctrl)

nodes = []
curves = []
# For each controller
for idx in range(m_sel.length()):
    mfn_dep = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode(m_sel.getDependNode(idx))
    plug = mfn_dep.findPlug("rotate", False)
    node_curves = []
    is_valid = False
    # Per Rotate Axis
    for idx, _ in enumerate(["x", "y", "z"]):
        child = plug.child(idx) #>>> returns <ctrl name>.rotate<x/ y/ z>
        # Assumed locked channels cannot be flipped or fixed easily.
        if child.isLocked:
            is_valid = False
            break
        if OpenMayaAnim.MAnimUtil.isAnimated(child):
            is_valid = True
        # Connect to anim curve
        connected = child.connectedTo(True, False)

        if connected:

            crv = OpenMayaAnim.MFnAnimCurve(connected[0].node())

            try:
                # Has actual animation
                if crv.isStatic: #>>> errors if the said curve comes from animation layer
                    is_valid = False
                    break

            except RuntimeError:
                res = cmds.keyframe(child, query=True, timeChange=True, selected=False)
                if not res:
                    is_valid = False
                    break

            node_curves.append(crv)

    # Is a controller with 3 channel anim curves
    if is_valid:
        nodes.append(plug.name().rsplit(".", 1)[0])
        curves.append(node_curves)


first = "100"
start_time = OpenMaya.MTime(first)
# Row is controller entry of animation for a given frame
rotations = [
    (
        math.degrees(crv[0].evaluate(start_time)),
        math.degrees(crv[1].evaluate(start_time)), 
        math.degrees(crv[2].evaluate(start_time))
    ) for crv in curves
]
```

Comment: What version of Maya are you using? Because I get TONS of basic 101 errors of improper use of objects here.

Comment: @GreenCell sorry for the late reply.. I am using Maya 2018 and its api 2

Answer (score 1):

If the animation was set-up using layers, your connected node won't be an *animation curve* (so it won't have a `kAnimCurve*` function set), but it's likely to be a *blend node* (some variation of `kBlendNode*`).

I'm not aware of any API function to get those curves directly, but you could check for the function set with `hasFn()` and use `OpenMayaAnim.MFnAnimCurve()` if it's actually an animation curve. Otherwise, if it's a *blend* node, you would need to get the `inputA` and `inputB` attributes on the node (these should be common to all the `kBlendNode*` variants) that should have *animation curve* nodes connected.